# What is the probabilty of lottery

Tags: probability

There is a lottry of 20 different balls.
What is the probabilty that the winning balls will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in two different lotteries in a row ?

I know that the probabily that the winning balls will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in one lottery is $\frac{1}{\binom{20}{7}}$, is the probabilty to get this in two different lotteries is $\frac{1}{\binom{20}{7}^{2}}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, by independence your expression gives the  probability that these are the winning numbers this week and next week.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hey, Thanks.
I have another question,what is the probability to get in 10 in a row lotteries numbers from 8 to 20 ? (only 7 balls can drawn).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the probability of its happening once is $\binom{13}{7}/\binom{20}{7}$. For ten in a row take the tenth power.

Comment: Why not ? $\frac{\binom{20}{13}\binom{13}{7}}{\binom{20}{7}}$, I know thats bigger than $1$ what is not correct.
But , can you explain me the Theory Of this ?
I have to choose $13$ balls, and then choose $7$ of them.

Comment: Do you know why this question and [this similar but different question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718362) came up within hours of each other?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are two events and are independent, then $P[A \cap B] = P[A] \times P[B] $

Two lotteries are usually assumed to be independent, so the probability of winning both lotteries should be $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{\binom{20}{7}}\right)^2$

Comment: In other words: yes.